# Nested FOR cycle wih a dictionary. How to start checking the second FOR from the value the first FOR uses

Tags: python

So I have a dictionary in which the tag is the patient code or name(string), and the number associated is the consult time(int). For example I have this:
`{'0001': 15, 'Charles': 20}` The person '0001' takes 15 minutes in a consult, the person 'Charles' takes 20 minutes.

I do not know in advance where there is a name or a number identifying a person(but they are both strings), that is, I don't know where Charles is located in the dictionary or even if it exists at all

I want to run this dictionary to check the patients that have the same consult time and if they have I want to run a certain function which is not relevant. For now I have this:

```
for pat_i in self.MD_dict:
    for pat_j in self.MD_dict:
        if(self.MD_dict[pat_i]==self.MD_dict[pat_j]):
           aux=aux+1
           funtion(pat_i, pat_j);
```

However I want j to start from i+1. How do I do that?

I tried using the range fucntion:

```
for pat_i in range(len(self.MD_dict)):
    for pat_j in range(i+1,len(self.MD_dict)):
        if(self.MD_dict[pat_i]==self.MD_dict[pat_j]):
           aux=aux+1
           funtion(pat_i, pat_j);
```

But because pat_i could be a string this doens't work . For example with pat_i=1 and pat_j=2 the code necessary for the if to work would be '0001' and Charles. But since pat_i!='0001' and pat_j!='Charles' it doesn't work

Comment: How many pairs of `(patient name, time)` do you have to work with? How much time does the computer have to get this done?

Comment: I don't know the exact number only that is always less than 20 pairs. No limit in time

Comment: What is `P_dict`?

Comment: it's a mistake! should be MD_list. I will correct it

Answer (score 0):

In the original dictionary, patient name/id is key and time is value. In the new dictionary, time is key and list of paitent name/id is the value.

This is the idea of making a dictionary for inverse look up and then combine patient name/id with the same time into a list.

```py
def make_inverse_dict(x):
    # Time is key. List of patients is value
    time_dict = {}
    for name, time in x.items():
        if time in time_dict:
            time_dict[time].append(name)
        else:
            time_dict[time] = [name]
    return time_dict


def f(p1, p2):
    print(f"    {p1}, {p2}")


def make_patient_pair(patient_list):
    # Triangular loop to make pairs of patients 
    # without duplication
    n_patients = len(patient_list)
    out = []
    for i in range(n_patients):
        for j in range(i):
            pair = (patient_list[i], patient_list[j])
            out.append(pair)
    return out


def main():
    patient_dict = {'0001': 15,
                    '0002': 10,
                    'Charles': 20,
                    'Ann': 20,
                    '0003': 15}

    time_dict = make_inverse_dict(patient_dict)

    for time, patient_list in time_dict.items():
        n_patients = len(patient_list)
        print("time: ", time)
        if n_patients > 1:
            for p1, p2 in make_patient_pair(patient_list):
                f(p1, p2)


main()
```

result:

```
time:  15
    0003, 0001
time:  10
time:  20
    Ann, Charles
```

Comment: Simply posting code with no explanation is generally discouraged. Only giving the solution does not help the OP or future viewers understand what's actually happening here and why their implementation was wrong.

Comment: Sorry but this isn't quite what I wanted. I don't want to know explicitely what are the patients that have the same time. I want to check if those patients have the same time and then if they have i want to do a certain function with those 2 patients. The content of the function is really not relevant

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your code is that you are iterating through it more than once. On the second iteration, you then check if `MD_dict[pat_i]` is equal to `MD_dict[pat_j]`. This means that you are going to get double the amount of data because at one point, the second loop will reach the **same exact** point that the first loop is on. For example, when the first loop reaches a value, let's say, "Charles," the second loop will first start at the beginning and then it will eventually reach "Charles." Obviously, the value for "Charles" isn't going to change between the first and second loop - this will result in an instance in which you would be passing "Charles" and "Charles" into your function, which is not what you want.

Let's say `MD_dict` is:

```
MD_dict = {'0001': 15, 'Charles': 20, '0002':15, 'Alex': 20, 'Jack':15}
```

What we can do is use `enumerate` to make sure these duplicates don't happen:

```py
pats = list(MD_dict.keys())
enum = list(enumerate(pats))
```

Above, `enum` pairs the patients' name and the index at which they appear:

```
[(0, '0001'), (1, 'Charles'), (2, '0002'), (3, 'Alex'), (4, 'Jack')]
```

Then, we can iterate over `enum` twice:

```py
for x, pat_i in enum:
    for y,pat_j in enum:
        if x != y and MD_dict[pat_i] == MD_dict[pat_j]:
            function(pat_i, pat_j) # apply function here
```

Notice how `x != y` appears in the conditional statement. This is to avoid pairing the same person with itself. This ensures that the second loop will not consider the person that the first loop is on. The result is:

```
function(0001, 0002)       # consult times == 15
function(0001, Jack)       # consult times == 15
function(Charles, Alex)    # consult times == 20
function(0002, 0001)       # consult times == 15
function(0002, Jack)       # consult times == 15
function(Alex, Charles)    # consult times == 20
function(Jack, 0001)       # consult times == 15
function(Jack, 0002)       # consult times == 15
```

However, there is one issue with the function above, and I am not totally clear on what you were asking for in the question. This problem is that the function will be applied to "Charles" and "Alex" and then "Alex" and "Charles" later on. This is because we run through the dictionary twice, so it's going to pick up "Alex" as a match when the first loop hits "Charles" and it will pick up "Charles" as a match when the first loop hits "Alex." If this is not what you want, we can slice `enum` on the second loop:

```
pats = list(MD_dict.keys())
enum = list(enumerate(pats))
for x, pat_i in enum:
    for y,pat_j in enum[x+1:]:
        if MD_dict[pat_i] == MD_dict[pat_j]:
            function(pat_i, pat_j) # apply function here
```

Above, `for y,pat_j in enum[x+1:]` will only consider the people that follow the person that the first loop is on. We then do not have to check if `x != y`. The output is as follows:

```
function(0001, 0002)      # consult times == 15
function(0001, Jack)      # consult times == 15
function(Charles, Alex)   # consult times == 20
function(0002, Jack)      # consult times == 15
```

Answer (score -2):

```
sorted_items = sorted(self.MD_dict.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])
for i, (pat_i, pat_i_val) in enumerate(sorted_items):
    for (pat_j, pat_j_val) in sorted_items[i+1:]
        if pat_i_val == pat_j_val:
           aux=aux+1
           funtion(pat_i, pat_j)
```